# modals that do not involve dialog windows

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy library out there to do something along these lines:

I have a page with a lot of elements. At any given time I want to be able to put a modal on top of the entire page and just highlight one of the pre existing elements on the page to draw attention to it.

Most of the libraries I've seen revolve around dialogs that pop up and then hide the rest of the page. Are there any easy alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: the only ones that I am really aware of are the jQuery_UI dialogs

Comment: The jQuery BlockUI plugin might be manipulated to do what you want.  http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Comment: I think the OP wants the visual opposite of BlockUI.

Comment: yeah exactly...I imagine I could try to block out every element on the page except the one I want, but as it gets more complex this will be hard.

Comment: I mentioned BlockUI because it has an option to block elements rather than the whole page. It might be possible to manipulate it to do what the OP wants.  But upon closer reading you are correct...it does appear to be the visual opposite.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I once saw a plugin that did this, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a BlockUI script, then raise the single element's `z-index` to be above the block.

However, you'll need to make sure it's in the same stacking container; you may need to move it to the `<body>` and position it absolutely.